# Getting a array in JSON PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to figure out how to get from a bunch of arrays the highest "tier": "VALUE" and get access to the entire array its in. In this case the highest "tier": "DIAMOND".

List of Tiers (Highest to lowest):

CHALLENGER

MASTER

DIAMOND

PLATINUM

GOLD

SILVER

BRONZE

I don't know how I can get each arrays data to find the highest tier and use that tier to gain access to the other data according to that array.

Here is the JSON file

```
{
   "29161162": [
      {
         "name": "Graves's Inquisitors",
         "tier": "DIAMOND",
         "queue": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
         "entries": [
            {
               "playerOrTeamId": "29161162",
               "playerOrTeamName": "ForsakenHound",
               "division": "III",
               "leaguePoints": 50,
               "wins": 234,
               "losses": 190,
               "playstyle": "NONE",
               "isHotStreak": false,
               "isVeteran": false,
               "isFreshBlood": false,
               "isInactive": false
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name": "Leona's Dervish",
         "tier": "PLATINUM",
         "queue": "RANKED_TEAM_5x5",
         "entries": [
            {
               "playerOrTeamId": "TEAM-4e132820-393f-11e6-8b2a-c81f66daeaa4",
               "playerOrTeamName": "Raging Turtles Alpha",
               "division": "II",
               "leaguePoints": 40,
               "wins": 12,
               "losses": 3,
               "playstyle": "NONE",
               "isHotStreak": false,
               "isVeteran": false,
               "isFreshBlood": false,
               "isInactive": false
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name": "Darius's Ritualists",
         "tier": "PLATINUM",
         "queue": "RANKED_TEAM_5x5",
         "entries": [
            {
               "playerOrTeamId": "TEAM-612b20d0-59c3-11e6-ae27-c81f66daeaa4",
               "playerOrTeamName": "Raging Turtles Reborn",
               "division": "II",
               "leaguePoints": 5,
               "wins": 8,
               "losses": 4,
               "playstyle": "NONE",
               "isHotStreak": false,
               "isVeteran": false,
               "isFreshBlood": false,
               "isInactive": false
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name": "Kayle's Lancers",
         "tier": "PLATINUM",
         "queue": "RANKED_TEAM_5x5",
         "entries": [
            {
               "playerOrTeamId": "TEAM-989e11c5-8c05-11e6-9e23-c81f66dd7106",
               "playerOrTeamName": "Raging turtles",
               "division": "I",
               "leaguePoints": 0,
               "wins": 5,
               "losses": 0,
               "playstyle": "NONE",
               "isHotStreak": false,
               "isVeteran": false,
               "isFreshBlood": false,
               "isInactive": false
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: What if you have more than one with the same highest tier?

Comment: First of all u need to use json_decode() here for make it an array

Comment: I already have json decode and that, im after getting to know after that how to get access to it. In a example. Also if there is more then one of the same highest its a bit hard as there is Tiers, Divison and LeaguePoints the highest in all that will be the top one, but I am just after example with Tiers to try figure the rest out my self

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group them by value of the tier like this:

```
$levels = explode(',', 'BRONZE,SILVER,GOLD,PLATINUM,DIAMOND,MASTER,CHALLENGER');

$tier_data = array();
foreach ($jsona as $unknown_key_id=>&$users) {
  foreach ($users as &$user) {
    $tier_value = array_search($user->tier, $levels);
    $tier_data[$tier_value][] = $user;
  }
}

die('<pre>'.print_r($tier_data,true));
```

Comment: Thank you, was a big help in understanding this